# Improper integral defined as one that the integral have one or more discontinuities or infinity.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Here is the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

f(x) have the limit as x approach to infinity (0) but f(x) integral from 0 to inf is infinity :
$\int _0^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{x}dx\:=\:\infty $

If a integral do have a limit, and the integral is an improper integral.
so the integral from 0 to inf must convergent.

This contradicted each other
Please help me understand :)

thanks!

Comment: For any $0<\varepsilon<A$, $\int^A_\varepsilon \tfrac{1}{x}\,dx =\log(A)-\log(\varepsilon)=\log(A/\varepsilon)$. As both $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$ and $A\rightarrow\infty$ $\log(a/\varepsilon)\rightarrow\infty$. Proper integrals ar in essence limits over finite intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the limit of $f(x)$ and the limit of the integral over $[1,x]$.

The integral $\displaystyle{\int_1^{\infty} f(x)\,dx}$ is said to be convergent when
$$\lim_{X\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^{X} f(x)\,dx$$
exists, which is not the same as whether $f(x)$ itself tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to infinity.

You can actually construct functions such that $\displaystyle{\int_1^{\infty} f(x)\,dx}$ is  convergent but $f(x)$ has no limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$.